# Polynomial x$^3$ - 2 is not the product of two nonconstant polynomials $f$ = $gh$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is an example out of Artin's Algebra book on page 334, chapter 11.

He states that x$^3$ - $2$ is in the kernel of the homomorphism $\phi$: $\mathbb{Q}$[x] -> $\mathbb{C}$ via the substitution map that sends x -> 2$^{\frac{2}{3}}$.

Artin's goal is to show that $f$ = x$^3$ - $2$ is the monic polynomial of lowest degree in the kernel, and since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, we have that the principle ideal, ($f$), is the kernel of $\phi$.

His reasoning is: "The polynomial x$^3$ - $2$ is in the kernel, and because  2$^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is not a rational number, it is not the product $f$ = $gh$ of two nonconstant polynomials with rational coefficients. So it is the lowest degree polynomial in the kernal, and therefore it generates the kernel."

My question is: Why does the fact that 2$^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is irrational allow us to conclude x$^3$ - 2 is not the product of two constant polynomials $g$ and $h$?

Comment: Hint: Rational roots theorem (or Eisenstein). Also for degree $3$, irreducibility over $k$ is the same as not having roots in $k$, because a nontrivial factorization is necessarily a product of polynomials of degree 1 and 2.

Comment: And the substitution should be $x\to2^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x^3-2$ is reducible over $\Bbb Q$ then it must have a linear factor in $\Bbb Q[x]$ implying a rational root but with $2^{\frac{2}{3}}$ irrational so is the only real root $2^{\frac{1}{3}}$. Therefore, $\; x^3-2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: What do you mean by “linear factor”?

Comment: @H_1317. By a $\it{linear}$ factor I meant a polynomial factor $f(x)=mx+b$ of degree $1$.

Comment: so does the argument go: if we are to factor f= (x$^3$ - 2), then we need a gh = f such that, WLOG, the degree of g is 2 and h is 1. Then the factor of degree 1 is of the form (bx - $\alpha$) but if (bx - $\alpha$) is to divide f then $\alpha$/b must be a root of f. since the only real root is the 3rd root of 2, $\alpha$ must be irrational and so that linear term over Q cannot exist. Hence we cannot factor over Q as claimed?

Comment: @H_1317. Essentially. Using the word "reducible" makes it accurate and more succinct because to be reducible over $\Bbb Q$ is to be factorable into non-constant factors. I think it helps to use words or phrases like "linear factor in $\Bbb Q[x]$" as it immediately indicates a rational root and helps avoid more notation.

Comment: when i use the fact that f must factor into a polynomial of degree 2 and degree 1 (ie both degrees less than the degree of f), this is evident for polynomials over Q, Z, and R, but is this true in a general polynomial ring? Im thinking not as if we are not in an integral domain then we could use higher degree polynomials and cancel the higher degrees easily.

Comment: @H_1317. $1*f(x)$ is always one way to factor $f(x)$ but this sheds no light on reducibility. So, $f$ need not $\it{factor}$ only the way you indicated. But if you add that you want a factorization of $f$ into "non-constant factors" then you're necessarily talking about reducibility. $3x+21$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R$ but reducible over $\Bbb Z$. In any integral domain an element is reducible when it is the product of two non-units.

Comment: @H_1317. And yes the notion of reducibility falls apart if we try to generalize it over all commutative rings.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\,b:=2^\frac13\,$ and $\,1\ne\,e\in\Bbb C\,$ be the such that $\,e^3=1.\,$
Then polynomial $\,x^3-2\in\Bbb Q[e],\,$ while

$$ x^3-2\,=\,(x-b)\cdot(x-e\cdot b)\cdot(x-e^2\cdot b) $$

**None** of the linear factors on the right belongs to $\,\Bbb Q[e]\,$
hence there is **no** decomposition of $\,x^3-2\,$ in $\,\Bbb Q[e].$

*Great!*

Answer (score 0):

Here we can use some classic one-variable calculus.

$$f(x)= x^3-2$$
Must have at least one real root in $x\in[1,2]$, since we have $$f(1)=-1<0\\f(2)=6>0$$
Together with [Bolzano's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) (really cool mathematician by the way, you should check him out!).

We can furthermore prove that this is the only root, since derivative $$f'(x) = 3x^2$$  exists and is non-negative everywhere. In fact the root is $x = \sqrt[3]{2}$, so the only factorization we can do over real numbers ($\mathbb R$) would be with the factor $(x-\sqrt[3]{2})$ but that number is irrational and therefore not in $\mathbb Q$ which was requested.